# How do I convert big numbers to decimal?

Tags: decimal, hex, biginteger

0x34363932353433373538323038353135353439

Comment: You'll need to give more info, at the very least what language you're using.

Are you saying you have a hexadecimal string that you want to be an integer?

Answer (score 2):

From the Unix / cygwin command line, you can use bc.

```
$ bc
ibase=16
34363932353433373538323038353135353439
1164362276596472215941024063897591129839055929
```

There is also [an online version](http://sciencesoft.at/bc/?lang=en).  If you want to do it in code you should use an arbitrary precision library facility, like Java's BigInteger, Perl's Math::BigInt, Tcl's  math::bignum, or of the many multiple precision arithmetic libraries that are available for C, like [GNU GMP](http://gmplib.org/), or [MPI](http://spinning-yarns.org/michael/mpi).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like ASCII to me! On a big-endian system, you get the string "4692543758208515549". :-)

Anyway, to actually answer your question, Ruby is useful for that purpose:

```
ruby -e 'p 0x34363932353433373538323038353135353439'
```

Comment: Output of that Ruby command: 1164362276596472215941024063897591129839055929